# OutOfMemoryError while downloading large file as byte array using retrofit in android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to download a large file in android.
The API is returning the file as byte array, I have added the @Streaming annotation as recommmended, however I still getting the error.

What can I do to solve it?

THE ERROR IS OCCURRING DURING DOWNLOAD.

My code:

```
//Retrofi api method
@Streaming
@GET(POOL + "DmListarDocsProjZip/{IdProjetct}")
Call<byte[]> dmListarDocsProjZip(@Path("IdProjetct") int idProject);


//THIS CODE IS INSIDE AN IntentService 
//consuming method
private byte[] buscarDocs(int idProjeto) {
    try {
        Call<byte[]> call = mApi.dmListarDocsProjZip(idProject);
        Response<byte[]> response = call.execute();// The OutOfMemoryError is ocurring in here
        return response.body();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("buscarDocs", "dmListarDocsProjetoZip");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        verificarSeSessaoExpirou(e);
    }

    return null;
}

Process: br.gov.sp.prodesp.viafacilbombeiros, PID: 27184
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 68706640 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 203MB until OOM
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:73)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at br.gov.sp.prodesp.viafacilbombeiros.model.DownloadDadosIntentService.buscarDocs(DownloadDadosIntentService.java:253)
        at br.gov.sp.prodesp.viafacilbombeiros.model.DownloadDadosIntentService.access$300(DownloadDadosIntentService.java:61)
        at br.gov.sp.prodesp.viafacilbombeiros.model.DownloadDadosIntentService$1.onNext(DownloadDadosIntentService.java:215)
        at br.gov.sp.prodesp.viafacilbombeiros.model.DownloadDadosIntentService$1.onNext(DownloadDadosIntentService.java:189)
        at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:139)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:41)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:38)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8553)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8520)
        at br.gov.sp.prodesp.viafacilbombeiros.model.DownloadDadosIntentService.onHandleIntent(DownloadDadosIntentService.java:124)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: `The api is returning the file as byte array, ` ? I think that just the bytes of the file are send. But you did not tell why you would put that file in Android device memory. You could save the bytes to file. What is it that you want?

Comment: Or are you telling that retrofit delivers the bytes of the downloaded file in a byte array? If so then that is not a good idea as you have seen.

Comment: `at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)` ??? Is that retrofit code? Or your code? Please show your code.

Answer (score 4):

Are your OkHttpClient add LoggingInterceptor to log body?
If you try to download large file , will save all body in memory for log.
That's easy let to OOM .

If you are logging body try to remove or just logging basic or header and try again.

If your code like this .

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(logging)
        .build()
```

Try this .

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(logging)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must save this large file to disk. It looks like that you are downloading it using the @Streaming (as recommended) but you're allocating it to memory, so the @Streaming is kind of useless.
For large files you need to use the annotation, so you avoid the memory leak during the download, but you also need to save the file to disk, so you won't need to allocate that much memory.

Comment: Massita, I am saving the file to disk.
The problem is that the error is ocuuring during donwload, in other words, the use of @Streaming annotation isn't making difference.